# data get from axios not sorted correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get `productId` from query then get all data related to that product. This data should be sorted by createdAt month (id).

I tried `.sort()` but that didn't sort my data with proof that whenever i click on send button on postman, i receive untidy data.

API:

```
//...
router.get("/income", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.query.pid;
    console.log(productId);
    //...
```

product.jsx:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getStats = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("orders/income?pid=" /*+productId */);
        const list = res.data.sort((a, b) => {
          return a._id - b._id;
        });
        list.map((item) =>
          setPStats((prev) => [
            ...prev,
            { name: MONTHS[item._id - 1], Sales: item.total },
          ])
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getStats();
  }, [productId, MONTHS]);
```

How to properly sort my data received from axios?

I tested Axios URL using postman and get method (localhost:5000/api/orders/income?pid=), it shows list of id (months) and total sales for each month:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "total": 170
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "total": 224
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "total": 200
  }
]
```

Comment: I've tested your sorting with the data in the question and it works, please check it again, the problem could be something else, maybe it's the data you got from Axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   const list = res.data.sort((a, b) => {
          if(a._id>b._id){
             return -1;
          }
          if(a._id<b._id){
             return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
```